# Wordpress Form To Email.php and Theme

Tags: themes, forms, email

I have some custom forms in my template pages. I'm using a form "action" to link to a formtoemail.php file. Everything works if I leave formtoemail.php as is, but I would like to call in my theme elements to style the page dynamically.

I have tried the following, but unfortunately get an error "Call to undefined function get_header()"

If I copy / paste the html from the page all works great, but I really would rather not have to update the html everytime. I'm sure there is a way to do this, but I'm not super PHP savvy. Can anyone help?

```
<?php

$my_email = "name@email.com";

/*

Enter the continue link to offer the user after the form is sent.  If you do not change this, your visitor will be given a continue link to your homepage.

If you do change it, remove the "/" symbol below and replace with the name of the page to link to, eg: "mypage.htm" or "http://www.elsewhere.com/page.htm"

*/

$continue = "/";

/*

Step 3:

Save this file (FormToEmail.php) and upload it together with your webpage containing the form to your webspace.  IMPORTANT - The file name is case sensitive!  You must save it exactly as it is named above!  Do not put this script in your cgi-bin directory (folder) it may not work from there.

THAT'S IT, FINISHED!

You do not need to make any changes below this line.

*/

$errors = array();

// Remove $_COOKIE elements from $_REQUEST.

if(count($_COOKIE)){foreach(array_keys($_COOKIE) as $value){unset($_REQUEST[$value]);}}

// Check all fields for an email header.

function recursive_array_check_header($element_value)
{

global $set;

if(!is_array($element_value)){if(preg_match("/(%0A|%0D|\n+|\r+)(content-type:|to:|cc:|bcc:)/i",$element_value)){$set = 1;}}
else
{

foreach($element_value as $value){if($set){break;} recursive_array_check_header($value);}

}

}

recursive_array_check_header($_REQUEST);

if($set){$errors[] = "You cannot send an email header";}

unset($set);

// Validate email field.

if(isset($_REQUEST['email']) && !empty($_REQUEST['email']))
{

if(preg_match("/(%0A|%0D|\n+|\r+|:)/i",$_REQUEST['email'])){$errors[] = "Email address may not contain a new line or a colon";}

$_REQUEST['email'] = trim($_REQUEST['email']);

if(substr_count($_REQUEST['email'],"@") != 1 || stristr($_REQUEST['email']," ")){$errors[] = "Email address is invalid";}else{$exploded_email = explode("@",$_REQUEST['email']);if(empty($exploded_email[0]) || strlen($exploded_email[0]) > 64 || empty($exploded_email[1])){$errors[] = "Email address is invalid";}else{if(substr_count($exploded_email[1],".") == 0){$errors[] = "Email address is invalid";}else{$exploded_domain = explode(".",$exploded_email[1]);if(in_array("",$exploded_domain)){$errors[] = "Email address is invalid";}else{foreach($exploded_domain as $value){if(strlen($value) > 63 || !preg_match('/^[a-z0-9-]+$/i',$value)){$errors[] = "Email address is invalid"; break;}}}}}}

}

// Check referrer is from same site.

if(!(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))){$errors[] = "You must enable referrer logging to use the form";}

// Check for a blank form.

function recursive_array_check_blank($element_value)
{

global $set;

if(!is_array($element_value)){if(!empty($element_value)){$set = 1;}}
else
{

foreach($element_value as $value){if($set){break;} recursive_array_check_blank($value);}

}

}

recursive_array_check_blank($_REQUEST);

if(!$set){$errors[] = "You cannot send a blank form";}

unset($set);

// Display any errors and exit if errors exist.

if(count($errors)){foreach($errors as $value){print "$value<br>";} exit;}

if(!defined("PHP_EOL")){define("PHP_EOL", strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS,0,3) == "WIN") ? "\r\n" : "\n");}

// Build message.

function build_message($request_input){if(!isset($message_output)){$message_output ="";}if(!is_array($request_input)){$message_output = $request_input;}else{foreach($request_input as $key => $value){if(!empty($value)){if(!is_numeric($key)){$message_output .= str_replace("_"," ",ucfirst($key)).": ".build_message($value).PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;}else{$message_output .= build_message($value).", ";}}}}return rtrim($message_output,", ");}

$message = build_message($_REQUEST);

$message = $message . PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL."-- ".PHP_EOL."";

$message = stripslashes($message);

$subject = "Dealer Locator Form from site.com";

$headers = "From: site.com" . $_REQUEST['Name'];

mail($my_email,$subject,$message,$headers);

?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<!--BKGD -->
<div class="blue"></div>
<!--BKGD -->

<!--Page Image / Title Area -->
<span class="hidden-xs">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
<div id="title">
<h1 class="pagetitle"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') ) {
yoast_breadcrumb('<small><p id="breadcrumbs">','</p></small>');
} ?>
</div>
</div></div></div>
</span>
<!--Page Image / Title Area -->

<!--Mobile Title Area -->
<div id="spacer"></div>
<!--Content Begin-->
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-9">

<section>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">

  <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.site.com/testarea/wp-content/themes/site/img/placeholder-img.jpg" width="262" height="222" />
  </div>  

<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<div class="entry-links"><?php wp_link_pages(); ?></div>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php edit_post_link(); ?>
</div>

</div>
</section>

  </div><!-- End col-lg-9 -->
  <div class="col-lg-3 visible-lg">
<?php 
 // Custom widget Area Start
 if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Dealer Search') ) : ?>
<?php endif;
// Custom widget Area End
?>
</div><!-- End col-lg-3-->
</div> <!-- End row -->
</div><!-- End col-lg-12-->
</div> <!-- End row -->
<div id="spacer"></div>

</div><!-- End Container -->
<div id="spacer"></div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the wordpress config file:

require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-config.php';

OR use a page template if your form handler is in your theme. Take a look at using page template's in wordpress: http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean about the wordpress config file. Also I am using page templates for the form pages referencing the formtoemail.php. Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: I've edited my answer but it looks to me like you just want to add a form to your default page, why not use a contact form plugin?

Comment: Because I don't like the added bulk and styles they input.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe consider the cloud (hosted) version of the script: http://formtoemail.com

Comment: how will that help with styling?